# f2py, problems passing a Python function to Fortran

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, f2py

I have a this simple Fortran code (`stack.f90`):

```
      subroutine fortran_sum(f,xs,nf,nxs)
      integer nf,nxs
      double precision xs,result
      dimension xs(nxs),result(nf)
      external f 
      result = 0.0
      do I = 1,nxs
         result = result + f(xs(I))
         print *,xs(I),f(xs(I))
      enddo
      return
      end
```

Which I am compiling using:

```
f2py -c --compiler=mingw32 -m stack2 stack2.f90
```

And then testing using this Python script (`stack.py`):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import cos, sin , exp
from stack import fortran_sum
def func(x):
    return x**2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    xs = np.linspace(0.,10.,10)
    ans =  fortran_sum(func,xs,1)
    print 'Fortran:',ans
    print 'Python:',func(xs).sum()
```

When I run using `"python stack.py"` it gives:

```
   0.0000000000000000        0.00000000
   1.1111111111111112              Infinity
   2.2222222222222223              Infinity
   3.3333333333333335        9.19089638E-26
   4.4444444444444446              Infinity
   5.5555555555555554        0.00000000
   6.6666666666666670        9.19089638E-26
   7.7777777777777786        1.60398502E+09
   8.8888888888888893              Infinity
   10.000000000000000        0.00000000
Fortran: None
Python: 351.851851852
```

My questions are:

- why the function is not being evaluated correctly?
- how to return `result` to Python?
- is it possible to evaluate the array `xs` at once in Fortran?

Thank you!

---

EDIT:
With the great tips from @SethMMorton I came ended up with the following:

```
      subroutine fortran_sum(f,xs,nxs,result)
      implicit none
      integer :: I
      integer, intent(in) :: nxs
      double precision, intent(in) :: xs(nxs)
      double precision, intent(out) :: result
      double precision :: f
      external :: f 
      ! "FIX" will be added here
      result = 0.0
      do I = 1,nxs
        result = result + f(xs(I))
        print *,xs(I),f(xs(I))
      enddo
      return
      end
```

Running `stack.py` with this command modified: `ans =  fortran_sum(func,xs)`; gives:

```
   0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000
   1.1111111111111112        3.8883934247189009E+060
   2.2222222222222223        3.8883934247189009E+060
   3.3333333333333335        9.1908962428537221E-026
   4.4444444444444446        3.8883934247189009E+060
   5.5555555555555554        5.1935286092977251E-060
   6.6666666666666670        9.1908962428537221E-026
   7.7777777777777786        1603984978.1728516
   8.8888888888888893        3.8883934247189009E+060
   10.000000000000000        0.0000000000000000
Fortran: 1.55535736989e+61
Python: 351.851851852
```

Which is wrong. This weird behavior does not happen if I add an intermediate
variable `x=x(I)` AND call the function using this variable `f(x)`. The funny
thing is that if I call `f(x)` once, the desired call `f(x(I))` also works.
After applying this "FIX":

```
double precision :: x, f_dummy
x = xs(I)
f_dummy = f(x)
```

then compiling and running, the right result is obtained:

```
   0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000
   1.1111111111111112        1.2345679012345681
   2.2222222222222223        4.9382716049382722
   3.3333333333333335        11.111111111111112
   4.4444444444444446        19.753086419753089
   5.5555555555555554        30.864197530864196
   6.6666666666666670        44.444444444444450
   7.7777777777777786        60.493827160493836
   8.8888888888888893        79.012345679012356
   10.000000000000000        100.00000000000000
Fortran: 351.851851852
Python: 351.851851852
```

It would be nice if someone could explain why?

Comment: If you add a print statement in the python function does it show what you expect?  The only other thing I might recommend is compiling with debugging flags on to see if something funky is happening that Fortran would catch with the proper flags.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. The compilation using `f2py` does not show any warning... I will live with the "FIX" for now, this is probably something caused by `f2py`, too exoteric...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Why is the function not being evaluated correctly?**

You are sending the result of the callback function `f` directly to the `print` method.  Because Fortran has no idea what data type `f` will returned (since it is not declared and it is not a Fortran function), `print` cannot correctly interpret the data to print correctly.  if you assign the result to a variable, then print the variable you should see the expected result:

```
double precision x
....
x = f(xs(1))
print *, x
```

**How to return `result` to Python?**

You need to inform f2py of the intent of the variables.  This is actually possible to do with standard Fortran 90 syntax, which I HIGHLY recommend doing since it makes your code clearer (I know you are using Fortran 90 because you are able to print an entire array without looping over it.).

```
subroutine stack2(f,xs,result,nf,nxs)
    implicit none
    integer,          intent(in)  :: nf, nxs
    double precision, intent(in)  :: xs(nxs)
    double precision, intent(out) :: result(nf)
    external f
    ...
end subroutine stack2
```

Now, it is clear which variables come into the routine, and which are going out.  Note that `result` has to be an argument to the subroutine in order for it to be passed out.

`f2py` will now understand that `result` should be returned from the `stack2` function.

**Is it possible to evaluate the array `xs` at once in Fortran**

I'm not sure what you mean exactly, but I assume you want to know if you can do this on the entire array at a time, instead of in a `do` loop.

*Possibly*

Since `xs` is an array, you should be able to just pass the whole array to `f` and it *should* operate on the entire array.  *This might not work*, because Fortran requires a function to be `ELEMENTAL` to do this, and this might not be within the scope of `f2py`.  If `f2py` does not make the function `ELEMENTAL`, then you must do this in a loop.

**An issue you might want to address**

The line `result = result + f(xs(I))` is assigning the same value to every element of `result`.  It is not clear if this is what you want, but it might be something to address if it is not.

**A code-based summary**

Below is an example of a version of your code using these new suggestions.

```
subroutine stack2(f,xs,result,nf,nxs)
    implicit none
    integer,          intent(in)  :: nf, nxs
    double precision, intent(in)  :: xs(nxs)
    double precision, intent(out) :: result(nf)
    double precision :: x
    integer          :: I
    external f
    result = 0.0d0 ! Make this a double constant since result is double
    do I = 1,nxs
        x = f(xs(I))
        result = result + x
        print *, x
    end do
    print *, xs
    return ! Not needed in Fortran 90
end subroutine stack2
```

Note that `f2py` will properly figure out the length of your input array, so when you call it you only need to define the length of the `result`:

```
import numpy as np
from stack2 import stack2
def func(x):
    return x**2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    xs = np.linspace(0.,10.,10)
    ans =  stack2(func,xs,5) # This was changed
    print 'ans:',ans
```

Comment: I've posted an answer that shows two Fortran codes with almost the same structure, but just the one that calls the function using the value previously taken from the input array works... This is weird. Could add some info on that to your answer?